# How to suppress warnings for API marked as depreceated. @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") does not seems suppressing it

Tags: java, annotations

I tried to suppres warnings using @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") for depreceated APIs. Tried to build using make. Still getting compiler warnings.

Comment: If you want to get a good answer, you will have to show us the code and show us the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated methods should be replaced as soon as possible. You can check the javadoc to see what you should replace it with.

One way to "suppress" the warnings is to compile your code with an older compiler where the methods you're using aren't deprecated yet.

Another would be to compile your code using -Xlint:deprecation

```
javac -Xlint:deprecation Application.java
```

Comment: The compiler argument would supress every warning of that type. As annotation contain information for the compiler it should be enough to supress the warning during compile. I'm not sure if OPs problem is intened behaviour but it shouldn't be.

Comment: @JorisRenting I think compiling using -Xlint:deprecation option will show the compiler warnings. Here I want to suppress them.

Answer (score 0):

`@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` does not work on imports. In that case - if you have the liberty to do that - remove the import and address the class with the complete name in your code. That way, `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` will work on it successfully.

Warnings:

```
import net.example.fancy.DeprecatedClass;

public class FooBar {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private DeprecatedClass depr;
}
```

No more warnings:

```
public class FooBar {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private net.example.fancy.DeprecatedClass depr;
}
```